# Why does LTL equivalence (with next oeprator) implie trace equivalence in finite transition machines?

Tags: linear-temporal-logic

I am following Katoen's [YouTube course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLnbFC0ntxiqdpoWwMKCVh6BRwBePHaqQx) about Model Checking.

I am trying to understand how finite transition machines are different from infinite transition machines in terms of equivalences. That lead me to the following [question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5841/trace-equivalence-vs-ltl-equivalence) regarding equivalences, but the focus there was on infinite transition machines. Comments in the thread claimed that LTL equivalence = trace equivalence in finite transition machines, when LTL includes the next operator but I do not see how.

The direction from trace equivalence to LTL equivalence is immediate, due to the fact that only traces satisfy LTL formulas.

The other direction is problematic for me:
If we have two transition machines that are LTL equivalent, I understand that they are equivalent with respect to finite traces, because I can use the next operator, but what happens with infinite traces?

If I try and assume the claim is false in hopes of reaching a contradiction, I get that an infinite number of prefixes from each infinite trace from either transition system would have to be in both trace sets, but where's the problem? Can't I express infinitely many different prefixes using a finite transition machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing to notice is that in finite transition systems, two systems $K_1,K_2$ over an alphabet $\Sigma$ are not trace equivalent (for infinite traces) if and only if there exists a finite trace $w\in \Sigma^*$ that is in one of them, but not the other.

Indeed, if $K_1$ and $K_2$ are not trace equivalent, denoted $L(K_1)\neq L(K_2)$, then w.l.o.g. there exists an infinite trace $x\in L(K_1)\setminus L(K_2)$, but we can say something stronger: since the transition systems are finite, we can actually assume $x$ is of the form $x=uv^\omega$ for finite words $u,v\in \Sigma^*$.
This "lasso" structure of $x$ tells us that there is a finite trace $uv^m\in L(K_1)\setminus L(K_2)$, for some $m\in \mathbb{N}$, thus getting rid of the "infinitely many prefixes" problem.

Now, we can define an LTL formula, using "next" operators, that states "$uv^m$ is not a prefix of the trace". This formula holds in $K_2$, but not in $K_1$.

Comment: Why do you need to consider lassos ? Isn't it enough to say that a finite transition system contains a trace iff it contains all its prefixes ?

Comment: @Denis I could, but then I would need Kőnig's Lemma, and for that I need to google Konig, and copy-paste the ő, and I was trying to avoid doing that (also, obviously I didn't think of that, and went directly to lassos) :)